# Re-use ASP.NET forms authentication token in JSP page

Tags: asp.net, jsp, authentication, forms-authentication

I have a use case where the user logs in to a .NET web page and then access a JSP web page (it's actually  the Pega BPM tool generated page, but i just made it generic to make it simple). The .NET application uses ASP.NET forms authentication and validates the userName/password stored in the sql database using a home grown authentication web service. The web service accepts clear text userName and password only.

Now the real problem, user accesses the .net web page and this JSP page is embedded/mashed up into the .net page. when the user tries to access the content of JSP page, I need to make sure that user is authenticated on .NET and if not show appropriate message or redirection for authentication.  Is there a way to inspect the ASP.NET authentication cookie  or token if anything is generated out of .net application's authentication process on JSP page ?

I can re-use the same internal authentication service, but for that  I have to transmit clear text user name & password over http.

any ideas would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I have been researching on this and found WCF Authentication service with a custom membership provider(internal sql db in this questions context) a close one. But it does not solve my problem since the first application accepting user's credentials is the .NET application and the ture issue here is how to carry forward that authentication session cookie/token to JSP page without transmitting the actual user name and password.